# Java ArrayList merge without duplicates based on a value

Tags: java, arraylist, merge, no-duplicates

I have a class called `Sample`, this class has a property that is an `ArrayList<Area>`, and an `Area` contains an `ArrayList<Elements>`

```java
public class Sample {
    private ArrayList<Area> sampleAreas;
    public ArrayList<Element> getMergedData()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public class Area {
    private ArrayList<Element> areaElements
    ...
}

public class Element {
    private String name;
    private Float value;
    ...
}
```

I need that the `getMergedData()` from `Sample` class merges every `ArrayList<Elements>` from each of it's area, keeping the element with bigger value.

Ex:

`Area 1: ("Element K" => 1.0, "Element C" => 0.5, "Element AS" => 15.0)`

`Area 2: ("Element K" => 10.1, "Element C" => 5.5, "Element AS" => 2.9, "Element O" => 1.5)`

`Area 3: ("Element C" => 2.8, "Element AS" => 0.5, "Element O" => 5.8)`

`Area 4: ("Element K" => 3.25, "Element AS" => 2.5, "Element O" => 0.1)`

So, that method must return something like this:
`("Element K" => 10.1, "Element C" => 5.5, "Element AS" => 15.0, "Element O" => 5.8"`

I can't figure out how can I do this in a fashion way.

Comment: what is the role of the `Element` class ?

Comment: The `Element` holds information about a chemical element found in a sample area. One sample have multiple areas, and an area have multiples elements. In one given area, an element is unique.. The `value` field is a float value that I'll use later for similarity comparisons.

Basically what I need is to transform an `ArrayList<Area>` in an `ArrayList<Element>` where each entry is the element with bigger value in all sample/areas.

Comment: how do you represent the string (for example "ELEMENT C") in the `ensemble` class ? a private field holding the name of the chemical element ?

Comment: The class `Element` has some fields, one of them is the element name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lists' elements are the same order, e.g. their `K` element is first, their `C` element is second, etc., then just do an element-by-element comparison. Otherwise, you can sort them on their element names and then do an element-by-element comparison (this is nlog(n) if you use a good sort algorithm), or else put everything in a HashMap with the element name as key and value as value.

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    Element e = list1.get(i);
    map.put(e.name, e.value);
}
for(int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
    Element e = list2.get(i);
    if(map.get(e.name) < e.value)
        map.put(e.name, e.value);
}
```